# React hooks performance and best practices

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React application I have the next situation. On each page I have to create this logic:

```
const user = useUser();
const message = user.auth ? 'Welcome' : 'You are not allowed'
    

<Button>{message}</Button>
```

I have to add this logic on 10 pages. I know that my question is more theoretical, but what is better in my case:

1. To add this logic on each page; or
2. To create a custom hook like `useButtonMessage()` which will look like this:

   ```
    export const useButtonMessage = () => {
      const user = useUser();
      const message = user.auth ? 'Welcome' : 'You are not allowed'

      return message;
    }
   ```

Won't the hook be redundant if it keeps only 3 lines of code?

Comment: Your code has no React code so it wouldn't be a hook but a regular function... There is **no React** anywhere here.

Comment: I think it's not a big differences for 2-3 lines of code.. If you think that is easier for you to use the function, do it.

Comment: Make a simple JS function like `getAuthText()` and just import it wherever you need. No React here.

Comment: What if the text _changes_?

Comment: @vsync, `there is no react anywhere`, if you would explain how to use `useUser ` hook in aregular function then i will agree with you.

Comment: @vsync, how to do a simple regular function if i need `useUser` hook?

Comment: @vsync, could you help?

Comment: Why are you insisting on a hook? No hook is needed because there is no native React hook used in your code.

Comment: @vsync, i use useUser(); which is imported from an external library.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like to create hooks with all relative things of a particular topic (instead of just one constant like `message`). For example:

```
 export const useAuth = () => {
   const user = useUser()

   const isLoggedIn = user.auth
   const welcomeMessage = isLoggedIn ? 'Welcome' : 'You are not allowed'

   /*
     add selectors, functions to dispatch actions, 
     or other util contants such as welcomeMessage
   */

   return {
     isLoggedIn, // use this constant across your app to check if the user is logged in
     user, // use this across your app to obtain the user
     welcomeMessage,
   };
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn’t create a hook for that but rather create a messages file where all the messages of the app will be stored

And then you can add conditional properties f.e

```
export const messages = 
{
 userAllowed: (authenticated: boolean) => authenticated ? 'welcome' : 'you are not allowed'
}
```

You can even take it a step further:

```
export const messages =
{
 Welcome: 'welcome',
 NotAllowed: 'you are not allowed',
 userAllowed: function(authenticated: boolean) { 
  return authenticated ? this.Welcome : this.NotAllowed
 },
}
```